# Raster data reprojection from 2D georeferenced raster data array by using GDAL/OGR library

Tags: c++, projection, gdal

Happy weekend!

I have a 2D georeferenced raster data (with a data type of "unsigned char") array. I want to use it as data source to do reprojection by using GDAL/OGR library. In "GDAL Warp API Tutorial" web page (
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180702062214/http://www.gdal.org:80/warptut.html)), all samples seem to begin with opening a raster file supported by GDAL/OGR. How can I set up a relation between "GDALDataset" and my 2D array without saving my 2D array to a file and opening it again?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `MEM` or [In Memory Raster](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html) format as a destination. E.g.:

```
hDriver = GDALGetDriverByName( "MEM" );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for my late response. I'll do as you suggested. But as I know GDAL/OGR has not implementd the function AddBand (please see the source code).

Comment: The [driver page](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html) mentions "The MEM format is one of the few that supports the [AddBand()](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#5b3704f0992f5170da34d940016fe095) method"